# C++ Syntax - Multidimensional Dynamic Array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need help understanding the syntax of multidimensional arrays in C++. In the book I'm learning C++ from, the code snippet looks like this:

```
typedef int* IntArrayPtr;
IntArrayPtr *m = new IntArrayPtr[num_rows];
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    m[i] = new int[num_columns]
}
```

My question is this: Why is there a star infront of the m? To me when I see

```
new IntArrayPtr[num_rows];
```

that's enough information to tell the compiler that it's an array of pointers that point to int. The star just makes it confusing. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: You need to have a blank line before and after to get the code to format, otherwise it interprets it as a continuation of the previous formatting.

Comment: _"Why is there a star infront of the m? "_ Because `m` is declared as pointer to pointer (same as `int**` actually). If it confuses you use `auto`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that's probably not that good an idea.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I was actually considering suggesting that in my answer but I was scared it would over complicate things.

Comment: @Quentin Why actually? Can you make any sensible reasoning (beyond opinion based), why not to use `auto`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Only reason I can think of is if the questioner isn't using a version of c++ which supports it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Hm, that *is* an optinion, but if OP struggles with what arrays and pointers are already, throwing in implicit typing probably won't help him understand, and may lead to the "fiddle with `*` and `&` until the compiler is happy" syndrome. But hey, maybe I'm wrong, at that'd be for the best.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ If he's learning about pointers and arrays, he needs to get it clear in his head what a pointer to a pointer is. `auto` at that point isn't going to bring clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that what you have when you do `new IntArrayPtr[num_rows]` is an array of `IntArrayPtr`s. In C [`new[]`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new[]/), "allocates size bytes of storage, suitably aligned to represent any object of that size, and returns a non-null pointer to the first byte of this block." So `new[]` is returning you a pointer to the first element of your array.

For example if `num_rows` is 3 this is what gets allocated in memory:

```
m --> [IntArrayPtr]
      [IntArrayPtr]
      [IntArrayPtr]
```

`m` being a pointer is what allows you to use the index operator on it: `m[1]` returns you the second `IntArrayPtr` in `m`.

Comment: *In C arrays are held onto by a pointer to their first element* - nope.

Comment: @Quentin Perhaps an over simplification? Could you enlighten us on the technically correct way to say that?

Comment: Simply drop the part I quoted. `new` does return a pointer to the first of the allocated elements (it has to, since you can't return an array). But arrays are a distinct category of objects, which only *decay* to pointers in certain contexts. I'm sorry if I'm nitpicking, but so many people get this wrong that careful wording becomes mandatory.

Comment: @Quentin I've edited to use cplusplus.com's definition of `new[]`. Hopefully that's technical enough for you but still an understandable answer to the OP.

Comment: Now I feel like a grump, haha. Thank you for your time, and have an upvote :)

Comment: @Quentin As long as the OP still gets it, this improved my answer. Without people like you I'd just run around teaching the next generation of C++ers heresy.

Answer (score 0):

m is the pointer to pointer which handles starting points of columns as a row. Example of this example in c

```
int **arr=(int**)malloc(num_rows * (sizeof(int*) ) );
for(i=0;i<row;i++)
{
    arr[i]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*col_rows);
}
```

if we use typedef,

```
typedef int* IntArrayPtr;
IntArrayPtr *arr=(IntArrayPtr*)malloc(num_rows * (sizeof(IntArrayPtr) ) );
for(i=0;i<row;i++)
{
    arr[i]=(IntArrayPtr)malloc(sizeof(int)*col_rows);
}
```

As you see, firstly we create a pointer array to hold pointers of columns. After that we allocate a place for every columns of array and assign starting points of one dimensional column arrays to one dimensional pointer array.

Comment: In C, you should not cast the result of `malloc`.

Comment: And in C++, you should not use `malloc()`.

Comment: Yes, you should not use but i just gave an example in c to explain usage of pointer to pointer.

Comment: Why do you think a sample using `malloc()` clarifies more/better for the OP as what they already have? It's only going to lead at least to even more confusion IMHO.